# Swift 4 alamofire responseSerializationFailed

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to send a request .post using alamofire but it is giving me this error:

> responseSerializationFailed(reason:
>   Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error:
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around
>   character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around
>   character 0.}))

I tried at postman and it works fine but in code gives me that eerror, I’m using swift 4.2

```
class func sendMsg(toUserId:String ,message: String, completion: @escaping (_ error: Error?, _ success: Bool)->Void ) {

    //let url = URLs.sendMessage
    let url = "http://tdlly.com/Api/SendMessage/18"
    let paramaters = [
        "to_user_id": toUserId,
        "message_content": message,
        ]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: paramaters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {
        case .failure(let error):
            completion(error, false)
            print(error)
        case .success(let value):
            let data = JSON(value)
            print(data)
            if  (data["success"].int == 1) {
                SVProgressHUD.show(UIImage(named: "cor.png")!, status: "message Sent")
                SVProgressHUD.setShouldTintImages(false)
                SVProgressHUD.setImageViewSize(CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
                SVProgressHUD.setFont(UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0))
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss(withDelay: 2.0)
            } else if (data["success"].int == 0) {
                SVProgressHUD.show(UIImage(named: "er.png")!, status: "message not Sent")
                SVProgressHUD.setShouldTintImages(false)
                SVProgressHUD.setImageViewSize(CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
                SVProgressHUD.setFont(UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0))
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss(withDelay: 2.0)
            } else if (data["success"].int == 2) {
                SVProgressHUD.show(UIImage(named: "emp.png")!, status: "message empty")
                SVProgressHUD.setShouldTintImages(false)
                SVProgressHUD.setImageViewSize(CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
                SVProgressHUD.setFont(UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0))
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss(withDelay: 2.0)
            }
            completion(nil ,true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `encoding : URLEncoding.httpBody` in your almofire request.

Comment: @iVarun it's not working